# Can't import from XML using Feeds importer and XPath parser

Tags: 7, importing-exporting, feeds

I'm trying to import book objects from the XML file you can see XML file [Here](http://paste.ofcode.org/whSwFHV5JtePjLbmVYzsG6). I will tell step by step what I did to achieve this, so it would be easier to help me.

1. Created a Book content type with all the corresponding fields from the XML file
2. Installed Feeds importer and XPath parser modules with their dependant modules
3. Created a Feed importer called bookImport
4. In the Basic settings I attached it to Book content type
5. The fetcher is a default one - HTTP
6. For parser I chose XPath XML parser
7. Processor is Node. As I want to create new Nodes for every single book
8. In the Node processor settings I chose Book bundle and everything else is left as it was by default.
9. In the mapping I mapped all the `xpathparser:*` source values to target ones from Book content type.

When trying to import, in the XPath Parser Settings for context I put **book** and leave everything (all the other book fields empty), I turn on my error messages and after clicking Import I get these two lines:

```
context :
There are no new nodes.
```

I've been trying to solve this for 2 days now without any luck, any help would be highly appreciated and I hope my post is informative enough, if there is something missing, please let me know and I will update!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved this on my own, the problem was that in context I had to write //book, instead of book. Stupid mistake which caused me headache for 2 days. I hope this will be helpful for people who will face the same problem.